# Dropzone.js image upload to profile photo drag-n-drop feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js to create a user's profile and make it more dynamic. The user would be bale to drag and drop up to 3 images through Dropzone and be able to pick one of those images as the profile picture. It will basically be a materialize card with the profile image on the left and the dropzone pool of 3 images that user has uploaded on the right.

I have created a dropzone form on the left for the profile picture and a dropzone form on the right for the 3 images upload feature.

I need help with

- How to set maxFiles to 1 for the profile photo(on left) and maxFiles 3 for the image collection on the right side. I changed maxFiles in the Dropzone.js folder from null to 3 but it did not work. It is Dropzone v4 so I am not sure why it didn't work when I changed MaxFiles:null, to MaxFiles:3,
- What do you recommend on how to create something that the user will be able to click on one of the three images on the right side and automatically update their profile picture on the left side.

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j8mf8k1v/

```
<div id="profile-card" class="section scrollspy">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Profile Pictures<i
         class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="imgOutput">
                <textarea id="imgSrc" name="imgSrc" class="general employee materialize-textarea hide"></textarea>
                <!-- Current Profile Picture:<br><br>
                <img id="imgPic" src=""><br> -->
                 Current Profile Picture:<br><br>
                  <div class="rightpanel" style="width: 500px;height: 250px">
                    Upload new images:
                    <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">
                    </form>
                  </div>
            <div class="leftpanel" style="width: 200px;height: 250px">
              Update Profile Image:
              <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div><br><br>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();"  />
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-reveal">
     <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Profile Picture Options<i
     class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Providing some code and an example, even a JSFiddle could help people to get a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve. You can check [ask] for more informations.

Comment: Hello HiDeo,

https://jsfiddle.net/j8mf8k1v/  is the jsFiddle

Comment: @HiDeo I have updated and included a jsfiddle